# How to add sig figs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, error-analysis

> Which one of the following answers would give the correct number of significant figures when the following masses are added together: 160 kg, 121 kg, and 133.3 kg?

Adding shows 414.3

There is one decimal place, so the answer also has one decimal place. I submitted 414.3, but it's marked wrong. I submitted 410, and it marked that right.

That doesn't make sense. Did the professor put the wrong answer in?

Comment: I think this (v2) is very close to being a reasonable question. If it were just edited to remove the last paragraph and ask why the procedure of using the furthest-right decimal place doesn't work, I'd vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

When adding numbers, you should consider place values significant only if they are significant in *all* of the numbers being added.

Here, the least significant place that is common to all the numbers being added is the tens place (because 160 kg is significant only down to the tens place).

That is why the answer is rounded to the nearest 10.

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't the answer just be 41?

Comment: Also, whole numnbers don't count in sig figs, only decimals...

Comment: 41 would have a number in the ones place significant, so no. - Significant figures rules apply to all places, not just places after the decimal point.'

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: In a calculation with significant figures, a number such as 160 is significant to the tens place only. The trailing 0 means that the ones places is *not* significant, and operations like addition or subtraction should be rounded *at least* to the tens place.